# Why do Apple headers not have __autoreleasing for NSError** params?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, out-parameters

Why aren’t Apple’s methods that take `NSError**` declared as `NSError * __autoreleasing *` ?

The [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) seems to suggest that they should be (?).

For example, all the routines in NSFileManager.h.  But I don't actually see *any* of the Apple headers using what is noted in the Transitioning to ARC Release Notes:

```
and the method declaration would typically be:

-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

Could it be because of supporting legacy code bases where all the `NSError * error = nil;` declarations are going to imply `strong` and so if Apple put `__autoreleasing` in there it'd cause a temporary `__autoreleasing` local variable to be created every time?  Only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double pointers to Objective-C objects are implicitly `__autoreleasing` as specified by the [LLVM spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters).

Comment: Interesting documentation link! That does not seem to match what is being said in the Transitioning to ARC Release Notes document where it implies that a temporary variable with matching storage type will be created.  ??

Comment: @Dad Those variables are created by the compiler for Pass By Writeback, they do not affect the storage qualifiers of the second pointer.

Comment: The document you reference is quite clear.  I've filed a request for documentation clarification for the Transition to ARC Release Notes document since it is confusing as written when one compares to the Apple headers.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I guess declaring the local variable as __autoreleasing is going to save the compiler (and a local variable register then)..  NSError __autoreleasing * error = nil;  [foo methodWithError: &error]; because  otherwise the LLVM spec & the Transitioning To ARC Release Notes suggest it'll create that temp var. Right?

Comment: @Dad It's not worth it to do that.  Let the compiler handle the storage qualifiers for you.  It's frivolous to optimize like that anyhow.

Comment: ha! :) Guess I'm showing my age - wasting registers by writing sloppy code was frowned upon back in the day...  You're probably correct that it doesn't matter in most situations now.

Comment: The Transitioning To ARC doc is quite old, and not particularly authoritative. It's possible that Clang's behavior has actually _changed_ in this matter since it was written. @Dad

Comment: @JoshCaswell Actually, there doesn't seem to be anything newer or more definitive at developer.apple.com... ?  Advanced Memory Management https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html just points to that TTARN doc.

Comment: @Dad: That's what I mean; the Apple docs lag behind the Clang docs (although the latter may very well have been written by someone at Apple).